# Инициализация глобальной переменной массива при вызове функции

Tags: c++, c

Есть ли способ инициализировать объявленный глобально массив значениями не при объявлении, а внутри функции так, чтобы не приходилось задавать его размер?

Конкретно интересующий пример, он, конечно же, неправильный:

```
float * vertices;
int main()
{
    vertices = new float[]{
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };
}
```

*Для меня C (C++) новый язык, работаю в основном с C#, в котором подобные вещи делаются очень просто.*

Comment: такое можно с вектором сделать.

Comment: Да, это я знаю, там всё намного проще. Но мне нужен именно стандартный массив, так как библиотечной функцией использоваться будет именно он.

Comment: У вектора есть мембер data(), который и надо посылать в библиотечную функцию.

Comment: Вот это уже интересней! Сейчас попробую

Comment: Здесь конечно важен контекст. Если у Вас обявлен и определен массив в программе то его и так можно передать в функцию.

Comment: Откровенно говоря - а зачем? у вас все эти инициализаторы и так висят в памяти. Ну так сделайте их сразу нормальными массивами, без всей этой динамики, и передавайте куда хотите. Что вы пытаетесь сэкономить? я бы еще понял, если у вас есть простенький алгоритм *вычисления* этого массива, а так? вы же все равно его по сути в памяти держите...

Comment: float[] vertices = {...}; - так? В смысле, мне то нужно, чтобы массив был не в стеке. Ну и инициализация чтобы происходила по вызову функции

Comment: Как это можно сделать?

Comment: В планах сделать несколько функций: makeCube(), makePiramid() и так далее. То есть функции возвращают массивы, наполненные координатами вершин и назначенными на них координатами текстуры.

Comment: Сделайте массив статическим - вот он уже и не в стеке :)

Answer (score 2):

Учитывая, что данные у вас константные, они так или иначе всё равно прописаны в программе. Поэтому нет какого-либо смысла выделять память на куче (если, конечно, потом не требовать освобождения через `delete []`) и инициализировать её в рантайме. Создайте массив и используйте его когда будет нужно.

```
constexpr float vertices[] = { ... };
```

Инициализация такого массива будет произведена ещё на этапе компиляции.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr auto make_array(Args&&... values) -> std::array<T, sizeof...(values)> {
  return std::array<T, sizeof...(values)>{{std::forward<T>(values)...}};
}

void foo(){
    constexpr auto vertices = make_array<float>(
      1. , 2. , 3. ,
      5. , 6. , 7.
    );
    constexpr float* c_array = vertices.data();
    constexpr std::size_t size = vertices.size();
}
```